# How to set featured section of home page to two columns?

Tags: layout

I'm working with a joomla 3 site and I need to change the layout of the featured section on my home page. At the moment, I have my modules showing up on top of one another in a single column layout. I'd like to change this section alone to a two-column layout.

So after doing a little poking around this option is not modifiable using Menu->main menu->layout and changing the column number to 2.

The is using theme1498.

Comment: It's template dependant. Not all templates will support this feature. What template are you using?

Comment: It/s apparently a paid-for theme, theme1498

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had to modify the template files and do the positioning by css.